# Changing Observations Based on Filters

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am have a dataframe that has, among others, two columns: `clean.data$bilateral` and `clean.data$if.bilateral.other.party`. Inside the bilateral data, there are three observations: `Y`, `N`, and `Bilateral` (yes, I know the observation is basically the same as the column name and that this is bad. The observation is capitalized, whereas the column name is not).

```
clean.data <- data.frame("bilateral" = c("Y", "Bilateral", "N", "Y", "Bilateral", "N"),
       "if.bilateral.other.party" = c("Jordan", "Sweeden", NA, "Uk,Netherlands", "Russia,Poland", "NewZealand"))
```

Treaties that are `Bilateral` or `Y` should only have one observation in `if.bilateral.other.party`, however some don't. For example, `Uk,Netherlands` should not be listed as `Bilateral`, instead it should be `N`. I've already removed spaces in the `if.bilateral.other.party` column, and there are commas between parties.

I am trying to identify observations that are currently marked as `Bilateral` or `Y` that should not be, and change the observation to `N` in that case. I also need to do the reverse, changing observations `N` to `Y` if they have other parties listed.

How do I do this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I added one, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Without an example data set, this solution is based on speculation and how you've described what you want done.

```r
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")
library("purrr")

clean.data <- tribble(
  ~bilateral, ~if.bilateral.other.party,
  "Y", "UK,Netherlands",
  "Bilateral", "Sweden,France",
  "N", "Germany,UK"
)
clean.data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   bilateral if.bilateral.other.party
#>   <chr>     <chr>                   
#> 1 Y         UK,Netherlands          
#> 2 Bilateral Sweden,France           
#> 3 N         Germany,UK

# Split and count countries and assign new bilateral column
clean.data %>%
  mutate(list_countries = str_split(if.bilateral.other.party, ",")) %>%
  mutate(num_countries = map_int(list_countries, function(x) { length(x) })) %>%
  mutate(new_bilateral = case_when(
    num_countries > 1 & bilateral %in% c("Y", "Bilateral") ~ "N",
    num_countries > 1 & bilateral == "N" ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ bilateral
  ))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   bilateral if.bilateral.other.party list_countries num_countries new_bilateral
#>   <chr>     <chr>                    <list>                 <int> <chr>        
#> 1 Y         UK,Netherlands           <chr [2]>                  2 N            
#> 2 Bilateral Sweden,France            <chr [2]>                  2 N            
#> 3 N         Germany,UK               <chr [2]>                  2 Y
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here are the results using the sample data you've provided.

```r
clean.data <- data.frame(
  "bilateral" = c("Y", "Bilateral", "N", "Y", "Y", "N"),
  "if.bilateral.other.party" = c("Jordan", "Sweeden", NA, "Uk,Netherlands", "Russia,Poland", "NewZealand"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

clean.data %>%
  mutate(list_countries = str_split(if.bilateral.other.party, ",")) %>%
  mutate(num_countries = map_int(list_countries, function(x) { length(x) })) %>%
  mutate(new_bilateral = case_when(
    num_countries > 1 & bilateral %in% c("Y", "Bilateral") ~ "N",
    num_countries > 1 & bilateral == "N" ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ bilateral
  ))
#>   bilateral if.bilateral.other.party  list_countries num_countries
#> 1         Y                   Jordan          Jordan             1
#> 2 Bilateral                  Sweeden         Sweeden             1
#> 3         N                     <NA>              NA             1
#> 4         Y           Uk,Netherlands Uk, Netherlands             2
#> 5         Y            Russia,Poland  Russia, Poland             2
#> 6         N               NewZealand      NewZealand             1
#>   new_bilateral
#> 1             Y
#> 2     Bilateral
#> 3             N
#> 4             N
#> 5             N
#> 6             N
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I added an example. Sorry about that. Is this still correct based on the example?

Comment: This appears to still work with the example you've added.

Comment: I've added the data processing results using the example data you've provided. To avoid rewriting your original data, I've created a new variable `new_bilateral` with the new changes.